# Debugging gulp, bower, npm project with Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, gulp, bower, asp.net-4.5

I have created a few projects that use AngularJS and WebAPI with Gulp, Bower and NPM for the build. It is a bit clunky as I need to publish into a folder and then run my gulp build and debugging is only possible through rewrite commands in the web.config file. Has anyone found a good way to merge these technologies without moving to ASP.NET 5? Moving isn't an option for me yet.

The best answers I have found close to this topic were in this link:

[Using Grunt, Bower, Gulp, NPM with Visual Studio 2015 for a ASP.NET 4.5 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872622/using-grunt-bower-gulp-npm-with-visual-studio-2015-for-a-asp-net-4-5-project)

but the topic of debugging was not discussed and bundling / minification only a little.