# Angular 2 with TypeScript in VS 2015 - loading components from different projects

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I have been working through the tutorial here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/ as well as various blog posts, and have managed to get it running in visual studio.

Now I face something I have not been able to solve.

I want to move some of my components into a separate component library project.

How do I then reference some of these components in my main app component?

They now reside outside of my app directory in another project completely.

What do I need to now be able to use these external components?

Comment: You need to load them up into something like npm or bower (via git) and then you can use those tools to bring them into your other projects.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, do you have any links to blog posts which contain examples of doing this in visual studio?

Comment: VS does not really have anything in it specific to this, you need to command line it. You can use the package manager console for the most painless experience. This is mostly based around getting stuff with them, you will need to find something else for publishing tutorials http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872622/using-grunt-bower-gulp-npm-with-visual-studio-2015-for-a-asp-net-4-5-project